# Tkinter to android translation

Tags: android, python, tkinter

I have a relatively simple tkinter program that just uses Event, Button and Label objects. I would like to translate this to be usable on an android platform.

1) What python for android should I use? QPython, py4a?

2) And on that platform, what GUI module should I use?

I'd like a little bit of detail for why you think a specific module or app would be best, as I'm just getting into the android scene and want to make an intelligent jump.

Comment: I would recommend try kivi, instead of QPython, its way better

Comment: I think Vinay is referring to Kivy, https://kivy.org

Answer (score 6):

Even for native purposes, most developers would advise you keep away from Tkinter. It's a dated and unintuitive library that often makes GUI creation and maintenance harder than it needs to be.

The main advantage of developing apps using a Python library and embedding in Android is **cross-platform support**.
These libraries will often allow you to port your app with ease to many different operating systems.

I will not answer which is "best" since this is an opinion-based question outside the scope of StackOverflow, however I will say it is (generally) easier to port from Kivy to android than it is in some other libraries (such as Qt). But take this with a grain of salt.
Most libraries nowadays offer advanced GUI capabilities built-in, and your choice will likely not limit you in that regard.

Either way, there is no direct/simple way to translate your Tkinter project to any of these, and you will likely have to rewrite it with the library you end up choosing.

I will add that if your intent is developing *only for android*, most would advise developing in a native Android language, such as Java or Kotlin, or using a development tool which makes use of such languages. This would result in smaller APK sizes and likely faster running times for your app.